# LINQ query: How to do case insensitive query?

Tags: xml, linq

Is there a toupper or tolower or similar functions I can use to do a case-insensitive LINQ to XML query? If so, how do you revise the following line of code to do a case-insensitive query? Thanks.

User types search word into textbox and I do this in LINQ:

```
where d.Element("ProductName").Value.Contains(textBox1.Text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where d.Element("ProductName").Value.ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToLower())
```

You probably should do some sort of null check though, just in case.

Answer (score 4):

It is very simple (and not correct)

```
where d.Element("ProductName").Value.Equals(
  textBox1.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Ok, edited - more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx):

```
where d.Element("ProductName").Value.IndexOf(
  textBox1.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > 0
```

Comment: (S)he's not doing equal, rather contains